# How to sign apk file with v2 or v3 programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I have made an app that signs apk files with v1 signature programmatically , but I need a way to sign apk files with v2 or up (v3 .. v4) like apk signer (in play store)

My problem is I can't find a way to create my own v2 apk signer

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ApkSigner library

```
Find com.android.apksig.ApkSigner
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
    com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.main("sign --v1-signing-enabled --v2-signing-enabled --v3-signing-enabled --v4-signing-enabled --key key.pk8 --cert cart.x509.pem app.apk".split(" "));
} catch (Exception e) {
    
}
```

You can use this code to sign apk or aab file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).